# R How to expand the horizontal range of ggmap

Tags: r, google-maps, ggplot2, ggmap

I'm trying to map location data on map by using ggmap. The points are defined by latitudes and longitude, and are spreaded out on a wide range of longitude. However, ggmap only allows for a square box.

You can download the location data here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/2s33ccpu4m3vsl9/data.csv?dl=0

[image: points populated on map]

The code I used to generate the map is as follow:

```
 geoCodes <- geocode("Kazan, Russia")

 map = get_googlemap(
    center=c(geoCodes$lon,geoCodes$lat), #Long/lat of centre
    zoom=3, 
    maptype='roadmap', #also hybrid/terrain/roadmap
    scale = 2)
data = data.frame (testTrain$lon_1, testTrain$lat_1,testTrain$isDuplicate)

ggmap(map, extent='normal', size = c(900, 900)) + geom_point (data = data,
    aes (
        x = testTrain$lon_1, 
        y = testTrain$lat_1,
        fill = factor (testTrain$isDuplicate)
        ), 
    pch = 21, 
    colour = "white", 
    size = 2,
    alpha = 0.4
    ) +
  scale_fill_brewer (palette = "Set1", name = "Duplicates") +
  theme ( 
    legend.position = c(0.05, 0.05), # put the legend INSIDE the plot area
 legend.justification = c(0, 0),
    legend.background = element_rect(colour = F, fill = "white"),
    legend.key = element_rect (fill = F, colour = F),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank (), # remove major grid
 panel.grid.minor = element_blank (),  # remove minor grid
 axis.text = element_blank (), 
    axis.title = element_blank (),
    axis.ticks = element_blank ()
    )
```

Is there a way to expand the range of ggmap so it covers a wider area?

Comment: A few ways to create rectangular shaped map are shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31316076/non-square-rectangular-maps-in-r-ggmap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scale_y_continuous()` option would allow you to trim the graph to make it appear rectangular

```
ggmap( get_googlemap(
  center = c(lon = 37.6173, lat = 55.7558), #Long/lat of centre
  zoom=3, 
  size=c(600,600),
  maptype='roadmap', #also hybrid/terrain/roadmap
  scale = 2)
)+ scale_y_continuous(limits=c(30, 60))
```

[image]